# Does accessing vector elements by reference reduce space complexity in C++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, space-complexity

I have a simple C++ algorithm that processes elements from a vector. I am passing my function the vector by reference, and accessing the vector's element by reference using a foreach loop like this:

```
vector<int>& gradingStudents(vector<int>& grades) {
    for(int& grade : grades) {
        if (grade > 37) {
            int n = grade % 5;
            if (n >= 3)
                grade += (5 - n);
        }
    }
    return grades;
}
```

My question is, considering that space complexity consists of both auxiliary space and input space, is it correct to say that my algorithm's space complexity is linear (because of the input size, which may vary)? Or is the space complexity constant because the input already exists in memory (it's simply referenced) and no extra space is needed except for my temporary `n` variable?

Comment: While references might seem like they're not taking up space (they're *Referencing* something else) implementation-wise that's might not be possible. The compiler might be able to optimize `grade` to not take space in memory (by using for example a CPU register) but otherwise references are often implemented as pointers, and a pointer needs space as well (on a typical 64-bit system a pointer usually uses *more* space than an `int` value).

Comment: With that said, on a typical PC-type system (which includes such systems as mobile phones) such micro-optimizations aren't needed unless you have *measured* it to be a top-two problem. Since you modify the vector and its contents you really don't have a choice about using references or not.

Comment: It very much depends on how you define _space complexity_. Usually, this term covers all the data, including input data. In that case, space complexity of your algorithm is **linear**. Additional term _auxiliary space complexity_ is often used that defines just auxiliary/temporary data used by algorithm (not including input). In that case, auxiliary space complexity of your algorithm is **constant**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are only using references in regards to your vector, you do not need any more memory. The only write you have is `grade += (5-n)`, and like any `int` (or number type) this happens where the variable is currently addressed - in this case the vector itself.

You have a single extra int allocated here as far as I can tell, and no other "auxiliary" space is used. Perhaps another one for the reference (like a pointer), though I'm not sure of that since the implementation may be using `grades+int_offset` to directly access the variable without an extra pointer.

Answer (score 0):

> is the space complexity constant because the input already exists in memory (it's simply referenced) and no extra space is needed except for my temporary n variable?

Yes.

The time complexity is O(grade.size()), and the space complexity is O(1).

However, if you remove the reference, the asymptotic time complexity described by notation `O` or more precisely, `θ` won't change here. Because that only affects the time constant spent to access each element.

Plus, copying a `int` won't take too much time, it should be almost the same speed as the version without references in range-based for(or even faster, because references are also typically implemented by pointers).

Comment: In your first "Yes" answer, did you mistakenly think I was referring to time complexity (instead of space)?